# How to run a Sencha Architect MVC application in Liferay

Tags: extjs4, extjs, liferay, sencha-architect

Does anyone have any information on how to properly run a Sencha Architect MVC app in LifeRay?

Designing, and running an app using architect(in a simple local apache server for mock up purposes) seems to work perfectly. My problem is trying to convert this over to use our LifeRay portal(ver 6)

I have tried to use Senchas build tools to create a jsb and build all into one JS script, but that seems to be missing required classes, and it says it is missing files, 

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - htp://localhost:8080/web/www/senchaTest/view/MainViewport.js?_dc=1350398599155".`

I have been searching for good info on how to run a Sencha MVC app in liferay, with the proper setups, but have not found *any* information out there.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

All the application which follow the JSR-286 standard can be intergated with liferay,does your application follow the JSR-286 standards?

Comment: Regular Extjs apps work fine, it is when the new ver4 MVC is being used, it doesn't know how to locate the sub folders(view,controller,model) even with Ext.loader.config set.  
Just wondering if there is something special for liferay/tomcat and war file deploying